# Regex Extraction - Mixed Decimal seperator

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently trying to write a regex in js that would extract the decimal numbers from a mixed string.

Example strings are following

```
mixed string123,456,00indeed
mixed string123,456.00indeed
mixed string123,4indeed
mixed string123,40indeed
mixed string 1,0
mixed string 1,00indeed
mixed string 1,00.00indeed
```

My desired output is following

```
123,456,00
123,456.00
123,4
123,40
1,0
1,00
1,00.00
```

If I run the following regex

```
(\d+\,)+(.)+(\d+)
```

it doesnot return any match when the decimal point is followed by a single digit.Eg. following cases

```
mixed string123,4indeed
mixed string 1,0
```

I am not sure how to tune the regex that works for all such cases. If someone can please help me would be very helpful.
The full js here

```
var str='mixed string123,4indeed';
str.match(/(\d+\,)+(.)+(\d+)/gm);
```

[image: Regex101screenshot]

Also I am getting this in regex101 which I am not sure how to decipher

```
A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `/\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?/g`? See https://regex101.com/r/YRDb34/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot. It worked. One thing I forgot to mention that it was required for IE11 application. It worked perfectly there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, [see an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66825067/3832970) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YRDb34/1).

*Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - zero or more occurrences of a comma and one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of a dot and one or more digits.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var texts = ['mixed string123,456,00indeed','mixed string123,456.00indeed','mixed string123,4indeed','mixed string123,40indeed','mixed string 1,0','mixed string 1,00indeed','mixed string 1,00.00indeed'];
var rx = /\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?/g
for (var i=0; i<texts.length;i++) {
  console.log(texts[i], '->', (texts[i].match(rx) || ["No match!"])[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex ... [`/\D+([\d,.]+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/QduIQl/1) ... of the below provided example code reads as follows ...

- `/ ... /g` ... globally match ...
- ... `\D+` ... any character (sequence) which is not a digit ...
- ... `([\d,.]+)` ... followed by a character (sequence) of just either digit or comma or dot ...
- ... which has to be captured ... `( ... )`.

Passing this regex to [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) does return an iterator object, which can be casted into an array. In case of (a) successful match(es) this array is not empty and can be [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ped into e.g. the desired end result ...

```js
const sampleText = `mixed string123,456,00indeed
  mixed string123,456.00indeed
  mixed string123,4indeed
  mixed string123,40indeed
  mixed string 1,0
  mixed string 1,00indeed
  mixed string 1,00.00indeed`;

console.log([

  // see [https://regex101.com/r/QduIQl/1]
  ...sampleText.matchAll(/\D+([\d,.]+)/g)

  ].map(([match, capture]) => capture)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The even more specific regex ... [`\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/QduIQl/3) ... straightforwardly matches a precise pattern. Thus the example code's implementation can be simplified to something clean like ...

```
sampleText.match(/\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*/g)
```

The regex itself reads as follows ...

- `/ ... /g` ... globally match ...
- `\d+` ... a digit (sequence) followed by ...
- (?: ... )* ... an optional and possibly repeating (`*`) uncaptured (`?:`) group (`(...)`) of following pattern ...
- `[,.]\d+` ... either a single comma or a single dot followed by a digit (sequence).

```js
const sampleText = `mixed string123,456,00indeed
  mixed string123,456.00indeed
  mixed string123,4indeed
  mixed string123,40indeed
  mixed string 1,0
  mixed string 34.
  mixed string 21
  mixed string 1,00indeed
  mixed string 1,00.00indeed`;

console.log(
  // see [https://regex101.com/r/QduIQl/3]
  sampleText.match(/\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*/g)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Might be worth making it require the match to end in a digit although the question isn't clear if this might be needed.

Comment: @dpwr ... You've definitely got a point; I did provide a 2nd, even more precise regex pattern.